# How to mix record with map in Avro?

Tags: avro

I'm dealing with server logs which are JSON format, and I want to store my logs on AWS S3 in Parquet format(and Parquet requires an Avro schema). First, all logs have a common set of fields, second, all logs have a lot of optional fields which are not in the common set.

For example, the follwoing are three logs:

```
{ "ip": "172.18.80.109", "timestamp": "2015-09-17T23:00:18.313Z", "message":"blahblahblah"}
{ "ip": "172.18.80.112", "timestamp": "2015-09-17T23:00:08.297Z", "message":"blahblahblah", "microseconds": 223}
{ "ip": "172.18.80.113", "timestamp": "2015-09-17T23:00:08.299Z", "message":"blahblahblah", "thread":"http-apr-8080-exec-1147"}
```

All of the three logs have 3 shared fields: `ip`, `timestamp` and `message`, some of the logs have additional fields, such as `microseconds` and `thread`.

If I use the following schema  then I will lose all additional fields.:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Log",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "ip", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "String"},
     {"name": "message", "type": "string"}
 ]
}
```

And the following schema works fine:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Log",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "ip", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "String"},
     {"name": "message", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "microseconds", "type": [null,long]},
     {"name": "thread", "type": [null,string]}
 ]
}
```

But the only problem is that I don't know all the names of optional fields unless I scan all the logs, besides, there will new additional fields in future.

Then I think out an idea that combines `record` and `map`:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Log",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "ip", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "String"},
     {"name": "message", "type": "string"},
     {"type": "map", "values": "string"}  // error
 ]
}
```

Unfortunately this won't compile:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar compile schema example.avro .
```

It will throw out an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: No field name: {"type":"map","values":"long"}
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.getRequiredText(Schema.java:1305)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1192)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:965)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:932)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.SpecificCompilerTool.run(SpecificCompilerTool.java:73)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:84)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

Is there a way to store JSON strings in Avro format which are flexible to deal with unknown optional fields?

Basically this is a **schema evolution** problem, Spark can deal with this problem by [Schema Merging](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging). I'm seeking a solution with Hadoop.

Comment: Your map has no name attribute. Give it one. :)

Comment: I guess you never try avro. It won't work. `{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Log",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "ip", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "string"},
     {"name": "message", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "addtional", "type": "map", "values": "string"} 
 ]
}`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The map type is a "complex" type in avro terminology. The below snippet works:

```
{
  "namespace": "example.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Log",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "ip", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "string"},
    {"name": "message", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "additional", "type": {"type": "map", "values": "string"}}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This schema will pass compilation. This schema puts all optional fields in the `addtional` field, e.g., `{"ip": "172.18.80.109", "timestamp": "2015-09-17T23:00:18.313Z", "message": "blah blash", "addtional": {"microseconds": "123", "thread": "http-apr-8080-exec-1147"}}`, but I want all optional fields at the same level of the common  fields, like the three example logs in my question.

Comment: Record in avro is defined as an object with a fixed number of predefined fields. Alternatively, put your map as top level object and treat all your fields as keys into that map.

Comment: If I use `map` as top-level type, e.g., `{"type": "map", "values": "string"}`, then all fields have to be `string` type, if there are different types of fields, then `map` is helpless.

Comment: You can define your map value type to be a union or named record type containing an union. Avro is quite flexible in this regard.