# How can I define an Avro schema which can flatten using Kafka Connect STM Flatten?

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am playing around with the flatten STM in Kafka Connect.

I would like to send messages like this:

```
{
  "id": "ywqPeozOoIpmjUZAkOVQ",
  "count": 1,
  "data": {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": "bbb"
  }
}
```

The **data** field is a map.
The number of keys in the data field can vary and values within the map are all string.

I have to use Kafka Connect Sink together with STM to flatten and send the data to another system (for the sake of simplicity, I am using a file system). So that, in the end, I would see:

```
{
  "id": "ywqPeozOoIpmjUZAkOVQ",
  "count": 1,
  "data_foo": "aaa",
  "data_bar": "bbb"
}
```

So far, I could do this using a JsonConverter. But every time I try to do it with Avro my Kafka connecter task ends up raising the same exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Flatten transformation does not support MAP for record with schemas (for field data).
```

My connector config looks like this:

```
  "config": {
    "name": "flatten-avro-test",
    "topics": "flatten-avro-test",
    "connector.class": "FileStreamSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "file": "/kconnect/data/sink_flatten_avro_test.txt",
    "auto.offset.reset": "latest",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schemaregistry:8081",
    "transforms": "flatten",
    "transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
    "transforms.flatten.delimiter": "_"
  }
```

and the Avro-schema I am trying is like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "count",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": "string",
        "name": "datum"
      }
    }
  ],
  "doc": "Event",
  "namespace": "Event.v1",
  "aliases": [
    "event_v1",
    "base"
  ]
}
```

Related information I have looked into are (among others)

- [Kafka Connect flatten transformation of a postgres record with array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360342/kafka-connect-flatten-transformation-of-a-postgres-record-with-array-field)
- [How to mix record with map in Avro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642154/how-to-mix-record-with-map-in-avro)
- https://rmoff.net/2020/12/10/twelve-days-of-smt-day-3-flatten/

But I still don't get it done properly.

So, the main question is :

- **How should I define my Avro-schema to make it work?**

but I am also very interested in knowing more limitations to this:

- Can the STM flatten handle maps with multitypes (strings, nulls, int, etc)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: As the error says, maps (within records) are not supported schema types for flattening... The only other option is to use a stream processor to write flattened records to another topic before using Connect to sink them. Source - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Flatten.java#L198

Comment: yes, I assumed that that was the issue, but since the error does not actually say "within records"  I got a bit confused with the terminology of 'record'.
I had also checked the transformation code before, but wanted to make sure and ask before creating a custom stream processor. Thank you!